# How to use Facebook API to get friends extra info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to build my first Facebook application and I have some issues. I want to get some info about the friends of the logged-in user. To do this I use:

> $friends =
>   $facebook->api("/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday,location,hometown");

and some more info, like gender, likes etc.

The issue is that this query doesn't work, no matter what fields I send, I get only name and id.

On login I have something like this:

```
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'req_perms' => 'user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_relationships,friends_relationships'
  ));
```

so I think that is not an issue of permissions.

How do I get all the friend(s) info I need? Where I'm wrong in the code I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_relationships,friends_relationships'));
```

Make sure you have an up-to-date SDK and go here [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Comment: Just works! Thanks for the answer. I'm new on facebook development, where do I find documentations/examples, on facebook developers website?

Comment: You can go here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk and look in the examples folder. I also included a link in my answer to the documentation for the PHP SDK.